# $dirty not working as expected when the input type is "file"

Tags: angularjs, file-upload

Am quite new to AngularJS. The issue is i have a form with two fields- name and profile pic as shown in the code below. I am using ng-upload (https://github.com/twilson63/ngUpload). I want the 'Save' button to work only if either field is dirty and the upload isn't happening currently so that multiple post requests are not triggered on the user clicking on the 'Save' button. But looks like, $dirty works fine with the 'name' field but not with the 'profile pic' field. Am i just missing something? How to go about it keeping it as simple as possible for a beginner of AngularJS. Any help would be appreciated.

```
             //Code
             <form id='picUpload' name='picUpload' ng-upload-before-submit="validate()" method='post' data-ng-upload-loading="submittingForm()" action={{getUrl()}} data-ng-upload='responseCallback(content)' enctype="multipart/form-data">
             <input type="text" name="name" data-ng-model="user.name" maxlength="15" id="user_screen_name" required>
             <input type="file" name="profilePic" data-ng-model="user.profilePic" accept="image/*">
             <div class="form-actions">
        <button type="submit" class="btn primary-btn" id="settings_save" data-ng-disabled="!(picUpload.name.$dirty|| picUpload.profilePic.$dirty) || formUploading">Save changes</button>
    </div>
</form>

             //In my JS code
             $scope.submittingForm = function(){
        $scope.formUploading = true;
             }
```

Regards!

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve... pls provide easier explanation.

Comment: Well, to put it more simply i want the 'save' button on the form to be disabled if either of the condition holds:
data-ng-disabled="!(picUpload.name.$dirty|| picUpload.profilePic.$dirty).

But picUpload.profilePic.$dirty does not seem to work, is it because it is of input type= file??

Comment: I think i have found out the solution to it after much surfing around. Am using the 'onchange' event on the form elements to trigger a function that sets a flag to activate/deactivate the submit button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used ng-upload before, but you can use onchange event of input element. onchange event is fired whenever user selects a file.

`<input type="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().fileNameChanged(this)" />`

Javascript :

```
var app = angular.module('MainApp', []);
  app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope)
  {
    $scope.inputContainsFile = false;
    $scope.fileNameChanged = function(element)
    {
        if(element.files.length > 0)
          $scope.inputContainsFile = true;
        else
          $scope.inputContainsFile = false;
    }

  });
```

So now you can check if `inputContainsFile` variable is true along with dirty check of name field

Comment: Yes, that's what i did actually :). Just would like to mention two more cents of knowledge i gained- first the single threaded running of Angular does make it an interesting case to make use of $timeout and second, an alert call to check the values set inside $scope.fileNameChanged() would not work (writing to a console does!).

Comment: @H sampat: Not working on IE 9 : element.files is null.

Answer (score 12):

I made a directive `ng-file-dirty`

```
  .directive('ngFileDirty', function(){
    return {
        require : '^form',
        transclude : true,
        link : function($scope, elm, attrs, formCtrl){
            elm.on('change', function(){
                formCtrl.$setDirty();
                $scope.$apply();
            }); 
        }   
    }   
  })
```

Comment: That's a clean solution! You're actually setting the form to dirty. Is there a way to set the element to dirty instead of the form?

Comment: i don't remember precisely, its been a while since I wrote that code, but I can look into it.  Is it accessible through the elm or attrs objects?

Comment: I don't know exactly. I tried something like elm[0].$dirty = true; then in Firebug I typed formName.inputName.$dirty, it returned true, but somewhere in my page my <span>{{formName.inputName.$dirty}}</span> returned false.

Comment: @futbolpal I am new to angularJS. Please provide an example on how to use the directive. I mean ng-file-dirty="<what value should I give over here?>"?

Comment: @Raja Did you find out "what value should I give over here?" ?

Comment: @EGHM No, I didn't. I used a work around of some sort. I don't remember what it was... I will try to find it, and if I do, I will post it.

Comment: @Raja thanks, I've got a work around already so no need.  It's not as once and only once as a directive would have been though.

Comment: @EGHM Glad to know that you've got another work around. Would you please post it here, so that others, including myself, may be benefited from it? It may also be better than the work around that I used...

Comment: It's not something people would benefit from; it's too specific, it's ugly, and embarrassing.  I cannot believe this is how it's done but have wasted more time than it took to implement trying to figure out the AngularJS way of doing it right.