# How to $setDirty input type=file field in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, validation

How to set dirty input type=file field in Angularjs ?

I need to form be setted dirty if file is uploaded through input field and so submit button be enabled accordingly.

Code below doesn't work.

```
<form novalidate name="newForm" id="add-new-form" method="post" action="">
    ...
    <input type="file" id="image_file" name="image_file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().newForm.image_file.$setDirty()" accept="image/*">
    ...
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-disabled="newForm.$invalid || newForm.$pristine" id="add-new-btn" ng-click="update(product)"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Save</button>
</form>
```

Comment: seems like you need to look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/22874923/2435473

Comment: @pankajparkar thanks, it works as charm! and pretty clean)

Comment: Glad to help you man..do search on SO before adding question